# How to put together some images (PNG/JPG) without using any image libraries

Tags: javascript, image-processing, imagemagick, jpeg, libpng

I need to combine several JPG or PNG images, to one large file.

Sometimes I need it vertically (For example if i have 4 images. 100 X 50. I need to create one images of 400 X 50.

Sometimes Horizontally (For example if i have 4 images. 100 X 50. I need to create one images of 200 X 100.

The question is, how I doing it, only by reading and writing bytes.

If you have javascript solution it will be the best, but f you don't know javascript, but you know how JPG/PNG files works, Please help. I just need an algorithm not the JavaScript solution.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I don't want solution with CANVAS element. I cannot use CANVAS because it's doesn't works on image larger than 2^16 pixels).
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393771

If you know about JS library, (not canvas), please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: 200*100 and 400*50 are both much smaller than 2^16...

Comment: ... and the bug mentioned is about specific set of operations. "Canvas doesn't work with huge images" is, well, a huge overstatement.

Comment: What do you mean? Combine two images? Display two images next to each other?

Comment: Create one image that display two images